# Disabling sleep/suspend mode in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend

Just started using 16.04. My pc is going into sleep/suspend mode after only 5 minutes. If you only get up to answer the door it's gone when you return and you have to log back in again. Annoying. I've tried System > Power and chose "Don't suspend", but it makes no difference. I tried the "30 minutes" option but it won't obey that either. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible you've customized Ubuntu 16.04's suspend settings in one of a few places but assuming you haven't you set it `System Settings` -> `Power`:

[image: Power Settings.png]

If this is set correctly chances are your screen saver is kicking in which will also require a login. It can easily be mistaken as suspend operation. Access it through `System Settings` -> `Brightness & Lock`:

[image: Brightness & Lock.png]

Comment: Ah, got it. Looks like it was the screen saver all the time. It's cured now anyway, so thanks a lot.